# Using ADB to make a phone call after a time out

Tags: javascript, android

Can the pc use ADB command android to make call?If it can,How to?

I have a text file containing a telephone number and a time.

How can I use JavaScript to count down from this time,and then use ADB to make an Android phone call to that number?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details on the Javascript part of your question? How does Javascipt fits with your use of ADB?

Answer (score 1):

To initiate a call using adb:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:5148888888
```